# Finding the file path of all files in a folder

Tags: c++, file-io, sdl

I'm trying to convert a bunch of images to textures using SDL. So far, I know its possible to do everything manually:

```
//Load front alpha texture
    if (!gModulatedTexture.loadFromFile("14_animated_sprites_and_vsync/text2.png"))
    {
        printf("Failed to load front texture!\n");
        success = false;
    }
    else
.....
```

However, I have quite a few images I want to load so what I'm looking for is a way to automate the process. I want to put all my images into a single folder, and then do something like this:

```
i=0
while (there are still images to load) {
     textureBank[i] = current image
     i++
}
```

I wast thinking there might be some easy way to just read in the file path of all the files in a directory, but I haven't been able to find a way to do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Comment: Note that SDL 2 still does not come with any way to do this natively, as others have suggested it seems like you will have to find your own cross platform option. The topic has [come up in discussion](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/filesystem-routines/9660) several times but there isn't any functionality like this in SDL right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any 3rd-party library like `boost`, just call the following function (for Windows OS). After this, you will get all file paths within given folder in `vector<string>`.

```
#include <Windows.h>
// folder must end with "/", e.g. "D:/images/"
vector<string> get_all_files_full_path_within_folder(string folder)
{
    vector<string> names;
    char search_path[200];
    sprintf(search_path, "%s*.*", folder.c_str());
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd; 
    HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(search_path, &fd); 
    if(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    { 
        do 
        { 
            // read all (real) files in current folder, delete '!' read other 2 default folder . and ..
            if(! (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) ) 
            {
                names.push_back(folder+fd.cFileName);
            }
        }while(::FindNextFile(hFind, &fd)); 
        ::FindClose(hFind); 
    } 
    return names;
}
```

Comment: @Nabla Yes, I will add this constrain. Thanks.

Comment: @herohuyongtao thanks for the help! I'm having some trouble though, the function you provided keeps returning an empty vector.               This is how I call it in my program: std::vector<std::string> directories = getDirectories("14_animated_sprites_and_vsync/backgrounds");             (I renamed the method).

Comment: @herohuyongtao I'm sure its just some silly mistake, but i can't figure it out.

Comment: @herohuyongtao When I watch it using the debugger, it seems to find the directory ok but never gets past the ! (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) check

Comment: @Adam Weird. I just run it successfully on my PC. Make sure folder `14_animated_sprites_and_vsync` is in under your project folder.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Are there any restrictions on the types of files that can be processed? I'm using png's.

Comment: @Adam I just realized that maybe your path is too long for `search_path[200]`, try to replace it by `search_path[500]` and test again. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Adam No, it has no restrictions. All files can be traversed 'cause the code search `*.*`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao hmmm, i know that its finding the folder correctly. when i put in a bogus file path it doesn't get past the (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  check.

Comment: @Adam Try to comment this line `if(! (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )` to see how it goes.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Oh geez, as usual it was something silly. The probelm was that since backgrounds is a directory I needed to include the final / ! Thank so much for you help.

Comment: @Adam Ooooooh, glad to here making it through.

Comment: @herohuyongtao ah, actually there is still a problem getting past the if (!(fd.dwFileAttributes && FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) check. if i remove the check it works fine, except that the first two filepaths read into the vector are . and .. respectively. After those two the real files get read in though.

Comment: @Adam Yes, it you remove the `if`-line. It will get your these two extra fake files. Actually, this is how the windows organize the file system. Just add this line to get the real files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SDL, I’ll assume you want to be cross-platform. The [`boost::filesystem` library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) can do this.

Take a look at their [directory iteration example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration).

Although it’s part of a 3rd-party library, `boost::filesystem` is proposed for inclusion in a future C++ standard, TR2, so it’s worth the effort to learn. It should eventually be the standard C++ way to work with files and directories.